# List roles that user has and all text channels in server - discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make two things, but so far I haven't succeeded.

**First:**

First is to mention all roles that a user has in the server. I tried making that but instead of mentioning the roles, it sent this:

```
[<discord.role.Role object at 0x0335A870>, <discord.role.Role object at 0x0335A970>, <discord.role.Role object at 0x0335AAB0>, <discord.role.Role object at 0x0335A9B0>]
```

**Second:**

The second thing is the bot to send the number of text channels, voice channels and categories in the server but so far I was unable to do it.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Comment: What version of `discord.py` are you using?  Try `import discord; print(discord.__version__)` if you're not sure.

Comment: Im using `0.16.12`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two commands should work for your purposes.  The first mentions all of the mentionable roles of the author, and the second counts channels of the server by their type.

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from collections import Counter

bot = Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def listroles(ctx):
    mentions = [role.mention for role in ctx.message.author.roles if role.mentionable]
    await bot.say(" ".join(mentions))

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def countchannels(ctx):
    counts = Counter(channel.type for channel in ctx.message.server.channels)
    lines = ["{}: {}".format(k, v) for k, v in counts.items()]
    await bot.say('\n'.join(lines))

bot.run("token")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the async branch, the Client class contains servers, which returns a list of Server classes that the bot is connected to. Documentation here: http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.servers

Iterating over this list, each Server class contains channels, which returns a list of Channel classes that the server has. Documentation here: http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Server.channels

Finally, iterating over this list, you can check each Channel class for different properties. For example, if you want to check that the channel is text, you would use channel.type. Documentation here: http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Channel

A rough example of how you can make a list of all Channel objects with type 'Text':

```
text_channel_list = []
for server in Client.servers:
    for channel in server.channels:
        if channel.type == 'Text':
            text_channel_list.append(channel)
```

Comment: It outputs as `[]` and not as number